# Is there anyway to tell the datatype in a postgres array?

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, sqldatatypes

I am using a Postgres 9.4 database and have PHP as my front end.

A general query I may run would look like this:

**PHP :**

```
$query = "select * from some_table";
pg_prepare($connection,"some_query",$query);
$result = pg_execute($connection,"some_query",array());

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result,null,PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['some_field'];
    echo $row['some_field_1'];
    echo $row['some_field_2'];
}
```

I am running into a front-end that requires to know the datatype of the column that spits out - specifically I need to know when the echo'd database field is a `timestamp` column.

Obviously I can tell `integers` and `string`, however timestamp is a bit of a different thing.

I suppose I could see if `strtotime()` returns false, however that seems a little dirty to me.

So my question is:

Is there a PHP built-in function that can return a multi-dimensional array of the database row with not only `$key=>$value` pair but also the `datatype`?

Any help on this would be appreciated - thank you!

Comment: There are queries to get this and there is also http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-field-type.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver Please post that with a little elaboration as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query from `information_schema.columns` and fetch just like any other query:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name='some_table'
```

Or after your query use [pg_field_type()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-field-type.php):

```
$type = pg_field_type($result, 0);
```

But you need to know the position of the column in the result so you should (best practice anyway) list the columns.  For the above case using `0` would give the type of `col1` in the query below::

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM some_table
```